# Usar NOT IN SELECT con LIKE, teniendo en cuenta acentos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero seleccionar los nombres (varchar) de una tabla que no aparecen en la segunda tabla:

```
select name from T1 where T1.name not in (select T2.name from T2) order by name
```

El problema está en que en ambas tablas tengo el mismo nombre pero en una puede aparecer con caracteres especiales (por ejemplo: T1 -> RAMON ORTIZ // T2 -> Ramón ORTIZ). Y en la consulta no debería aparecer, pero aparece. Porque compara que ambas cadenas son exactamente iguales. Por lo tanto, necesito usar LIKE'%%' para evitar mayúsculas y minúsculas y caracteres especiales. Algo como:

```
select name from T1 where T1.name not in LIKE '%(select T2.name from T2)%' order by name
```

¿Cómo hago eso?

Comment: Es decir, ¿querés que tu consulta también tenga en cuenta los acentos? Ej.: si en _t1_ está _RAMON ORTIZ_ y en _t2_ está _Ramón ORTIZ_, ese nombre **no** debería aparecer entre los resultados de la consulta.

Comment: Efectivamente, ya que aunque están escritos de forma distinta, son el mismo (tanto acentos como mayúsculas/minúsculas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres hacer, tendrías que usar `COLLATE`. Lo que haces con `COLLATE` es indicarle si quieres que ignore el CASE (mayúsculas o minúsculas) y/o los acentos.

Entonces como quieres obviar los acentos y mayúsculas y minúsculas de la T1 tendrías que aplicarlo al primer SELECT de T1. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```sql
select name 
from T1 
where T1.name COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI not in (select T2.name from T2)
order by name
```

Con *CI* le indicas *CASE IGNORE* y con *AI* le indicas *ACCENT IGNORE*.

Comment: Gracias, pero realmente podrían aparecer en ambas tablas. Osea, puede que en el ejemplo anterior era: T1 -> RAMON ORTIZ // T2 -> Ramón ORTIZ, pero luego puedo encontrarme T1 -> Miguelón CARRASPÓN/ / T2-> miguel carraspon. Siendo esto así, ¿habría que cambiar algo más en tu query?

Comment: Tendrías que aplicar la misma clausula a la segunda consulta a la T2:

`select name COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI from T1 where T1.name not in (select T2.name COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI from T2) order by name` .

En este caso quizás quedaría mejor aplicar la clausula en el `select` y no en el `where`.